# Почему Google Chrome не принимает расширение и "ругается" на json?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, расширения, google-extensions

Пытаюсь создать extension для Chrome и столкнулся с такой проблемой: беру файл manifest.json, который дан как образец самим "Хромом", беру пример вставки "content-scripts" от него же (ничего не меняю абсолютно).

загружаю в `chrome://extensions/`

manifest.json у меня не принимается, пишет:

```
Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 28, column: 2, Syntax error.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал по всякому. Заметил, что квадратные скобки "content-scripts" не очень соответствуют формату всего остального. Никак не пойму, в чем ошибка? Вроде бы все - примеры самого гугл хрома.

**Актуальный скрин:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот ошибка именно из-за того, что вы ничего не меняете абсолютно — надо было запятую поставить.

Comment: А где? Везде перепробовал поставить по вашей рекомендации, но json браузер все равно не "хавает"

Comment: После `"manifest_version": 2`

Comment: А вот на `],` в конце запятую наоборот нужно убрать

Comment: C тем же результатом, ни то, ни другое не срабатывает...

Comment: Почему не срабатывает, что пишет? Если вы файл меняли, то результат быть «тем же» однозначно не может

Comment: {
     "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
     "css": ["myStyles.css"],
     "js": ["contentScript.js"]
   },
 ]
},

Comment: а пишет следующее: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 28, column: 2, Syntax error.

Comment: Чёрт вас знает что вы делаете, но в этом комментарии вы зачем-то добавили две лишние запятые

Comment: "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
     "css": ["myStyles.css"],
     "js": ["contentScript.js"]
   }
 ]
},

Comment: если я вас правильно понял..

Comment: Ничего не понятно, перезапустите браузер и покажите актуальный скриншот и актуальный текст ошибки

Comment: загрузил актуальный в вопрос.. А ошибку вот какую выдает: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 28, column: 2, Syntax error.

Comment: На втором скриншоте запятая после `"manifest_version": 2` так до сих пор и не появилась... Может вы лучше сходите всё-таки почитаете про основы JSON, чем запятые куда попало ставить?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста на 1 скрин, там ], а на втором ] без запятой..

Comment: Или я Вас неправильно понял, что нужно изменить?

Comment: Поставить запятую после `"manifest_version": 2` — ни на одном из скриншотов этой запятой нет, но она должна быть.

Comment: заменил нижний скрин..

Comment: он с запятой.. вот ошибка: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 35, column: 2, Unexpected data after root element.

Comment: И эту запятую на конце `},` тоже нужно убрать, не знаю зачем вы её написали

Comment: Убрал запятую, теперь пишет: Не удается загрузить javascript "contentScript.js" для скрипта содержимого.

Comment: @andreymal, огромное вам спасибо! Последняя ошибка была связана просто с тем, что нужных файлов на которые ссылается json - не было.. Сейчас все в порядке..

Comment: Valentine приобрел внимательное отношение к синтаксису и чувствует себя Атлично

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116410/discussion-on-question-by-valentin--google-chrome---).